# How to check/pass setting status

Tags: java, android

I have a preferences class that allows the user to turn on 'hints' from the settings of the application:

```
public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {
//Option names and defualt values
private static final String OPT_HINTS = "hints";
private static final boolean OPT_HINTS_DEF = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
}
/**Get the current value of the hints option */
public static boolean getHints(Context context) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean(OPT_HINTS, OPT_HINTS_DEF);

}
}
```

The xml file contains:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="hints"
    android:title="@string/hints_title"
    android:summary="@string/hints_summary"
    android:defaultValue="true" />
```

How can I check if 'hints' is set On. Then if it is set On, I want to allow the application to do a certain thing.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

> How can I check if 'hints' is set On. Then if it is set On, I want to allow the application to do a certain thing.

Using your code simply call:

```
if(getHints(this)) {
    // The preference is checked, do something
}
else {
    // The preference isn't checked
}
```

Though it might be easier to save `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)` in a class variable as you add more preferences.

Comment: does the method 'getHints' need to be in the same Activity/class it is being called from?

Comment: I hadn't noticed that you want it to be static, in this case you must use `Prefs.getHints(this)` and as long as the Activities share the same Context you should be fine.  (If you are having trouble getting a value out try using `getApplicationContext()`.)